# Access to samba share folder without browsing

Tags: samba, rhel7

I am setting up a samba server on RHEL7. I would like to set up my share permission in the following manner -

Directory shared -

```
/shared/
/shared/private/

Files in /shared/ -
/shared/file1
/shared/file2
```

I want to allow user to access to file1,file2 and private direcotry without allowing them to browse /shared/ directory.

User should not see what is inside /shared/ directory but if they know the exact file and directory name in /shared/, they should be able to access it via full path.

Can it be done?

Thanks,

Comment: off hand, I seem to think per file/directory permissions (without a forced permissions setting) on samba should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that quite easily by removing the "r" permission on /shared/
Something as that: **`chmod go-r shared`**

After that command, if the user try do access the /shared/ folder it will be a "access denied" message. But if it explicitly enter a file's complete path (eg: /shared/file1) it can access the file.